# DATEADD con linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Tengo la siguiente consulta en sql y necesito utilizar linq...

```
SELECT * FROM Periodo
  where valorIndicador is not null AND convocatoria = 'Cvc1450'
  and fechaIni <= '2019-12-01' and fechaFin >= DATEADD(Month,-1,'2019-12-01')
```

lo que tengo de linq es algo parecido a esto

```
 var lstPeriodo = list.where(x.FechaIni <= MesCalculo && x.FechaFin >= 
                          MesCalculo).OrderByDescending(x => x.FechaFin aca es donde
                          necesito algo como un dateadd(month
```

con linq existe una función que pueda restar un mes a la fecha?

Comment: Me parece bien que tengas la query, ¿dónde está el intento de tu expresión lambda o un LINQ statement? Estaría genial que haya algún intento :) Revisa https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: @fredyfx si por realizar la pregunta no coloque lo intentado, gracias

Comment: es fácil, converte ambos tipos a DateTime, y ahi tienes el método que buscas

Comment: por cierto, no debería ser +1 en vez de -1 el mes a sumar?

Comment: ¡Perfecto hermano! Considera que los intentos siempre son muy bien vistos en la comunidad, me alegra que @Iria pudo solucionarte la pregunta, buenas vibras para todos :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yo haría algo así:

```
lstPeriodo = list.Where(l => l.valorIndicador != null && l.convocatoria == 'Cvc1450')
                 .Where(l => new DateTime(l.fechaIni) <= new DateTime('2019-12-01') 
                        && new DateTime(l.fechaFin) >= (new DateTime('2019-12-01')).AddMonths(-1));
```

Por cierto, los dos `where()` se pueden unir en uno solo.

Suponiendo que tal y como lo tengas configurado fechaFin y fechaIni sean de tipo string. Y que realmente quieras restar y no sumar un mes, como tienes en la SQL query.

Para más información: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/system-datetime-methods